# Using `map` to Create New Array of Objects with Fewer Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wanting to use `map` to create a new array of of objects that have two properties from the original objects in the originating array, so I am trying this:

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module =>
  module.name, module.configurables
);
```

But this isn't working, as only the "name" is saved to the new array. What am I missing here?

I also tried this:

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module => {
  name: module.name,
  configurables: module.configurables
});
```

... but end up with a syntax error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'`

Comment: configurableModules.map(module =>({
  name: module.name, configurables: module.configurables
}));

Comment: If you want to return an object, enclose it in `{}`. Try `configurableModules.map(module =>({ module.name, module.configurables }))`.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: const mapped = [{id: 1, data: 'thing'}, {id: 2, data: 'thing'}].map(item => ({ id: item.id * 10, data: item.thing + ' another thing' })). This works. just tried it, which means the syntax Andrey provided is valid

Comment: See Siddharth's answer below: the key was the extra parentheses around the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I see you want to `map` from one array to another. You can do it in 2 ways:

***Inline***

```
  const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module => ({name: module.name, configurables: module.configurables}));
```

When you do inline and return an object you have to wrap it in parenthesis so that it gets evaluated properly.

***Use Return Statement***

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module => {
  return {
    name: module.name,
    configurables: module.configurables
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little?

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Key was the extra parentheses around the object.

Comment: this is because the shorthand fat arrow and returning an object dont go well together. runtime cant tell if youre trying to use a function block or an object.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap it with parentheses as follow:

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(({name, configurables})=> ({
  name,
  configurables
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object on the arrow function from the map:

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module =>
  ({ name: module.name, configurables: module.configurables })
);
```

this return an array of objects with name and module fields.

If you return an object, you need to use parenthesis because otherwise it will be treated as a code body with no return.

Comment: this is because the shorthand fat arrow and returning an object dont go well together. runtime cant tell if youre trying to use a function block or an object.

Comment: Just wrap the object in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if i understand your question correctly

```
const filteredConfigurableModules = configurableModules.map(module => ({
  name : module.name,
  configurables : module.configurables,
}));
```